# Avoiding adding Same UserControl in Canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, user-controls, enumeration

I am using Canvas in WPF Window to show UserControl.
I dont want to add the same UserControl in the Canvas.

How can i do that?

Current i have done..

```
private void OpenChild(UserControl ctrl)
{            
    ctrl.Uid = ctrl.Name;
    if (JIMSCanvas.Children.Count == 0)
    {                
        JIMSCanvas.Children.Add(ctrl);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in JIMSCanvas.Children)
        {
            if (child.Uid == ctrl.Uid)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already");
            }
            else
            {
                JIMSCanvas.Children.Add(ctrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and adding a UserControl like this

```
OpenChild(new JIMS.View.Ledger());
```

It works for me but when i add an other Control like

```
OpenChild(new JIMS.View.Stock());
```

Its throwing an exception called

> The enumerator is not valid because the collection changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you're modifying the enumeration while in the process of cycling through it (inside the **foreach**).  Just have to use a method that doesn't alter the enumeration:

```
bool alreadyExists = false;
UIElement existingElement = null;
foreach (UIElement child in JIMSCanvas.Children)
{
    if (child.Uid == ctrl.Uid)
    {
        alreadyExists = true;
        existingElement = child;
    }
}
if (alreadyExists)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already");
    existingElement.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
else
{
    JIMSCanvas.Children.Add(ctrl);
}
```

Comment: but instead of showing Message i want to change `child.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;`

Comment: See my update-- you can just set a reference to the existing child and access it afterwards.

Comment: One final doubt, if there are two are three usercontrol in canvas and once i click again to open that UserControl this code will not open but i want to make the focus of that control on top of other control

Comment: @KishoreJangid hmm, I'm not sure, but I think you can use the **Z Index** property to move canvas children to the front.  If not, I'd recommend opening another question or look for similar ones on SO.

Comment: i there are many UserControl then it will become hard to get by ZIndex since i have to change ZIndex of each control above the othercontrol

Answer (score 0):

Or more simply

```
if (JIMSCanvas.Children.Any(c => c.Uid == ctrl.Uid)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Already"); 
}
else
{
   JIMSCanvas.Children.Add(ctrl); 
}
```

Comment: Linq Queries are not possible on Canvas Children since it doesnot implement IEnumerable Interface